# crash ORMLite on Android with proguard

Tags: android, proguard, ormlite

everything is okay until i proguard it.
here is my proguard-project.txt

```
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }
-keep class com.liba.carpool.db.**
-keepclassmembers class com.liba.carpool.db.** { *; } 
-keepattributes Signature
```

here's the logcat:

> 10-29 16:11:24.616: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 10-29 16:11:24.616:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12870):  at
>   com.j256.ormlite.db.SqliteAndroidDatabaseType.extractDatabaseTableConfig(Unknown
>   Source) 10-29 16:11:24.616: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):  at
>   com.j256.ormlite.dao.DaoManager.createDao(Unknown Source) 10-29
>   16:11:24.616: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at
>   com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.getDao(Unknown
>   Source) 10-29 16:11:24.616: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):  at
>   com.liba.carpool.db.MappingRouteRepository.(Unknown Source)
>   10-29 16:11:24.616: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):  at
>   com.liba.carpool.db.MyRouteRepository.(Unknown Source) 10-29
>   16:11:24.616: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at
>   com.liba.carpool.a.a.loadCarpools(Unknown Source) 10-29 16:11:24.616:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12870):  at
>   com.liba.carpool.DemoApplication.onCreate(Unknown Source) 10-29
>   16:11:24.616: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:981)
>   10-29 16:11:24.616: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4462)
>   10-29 16:11:24.616: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139) 10-29
>   16:11:24.616: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
>   10-29 16:11:24.616: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-29
>   16:11:24.616: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 10-29 16:11:24.616:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12870):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945) 10-29
>   16:11:24.616: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-29
>   16:11:24.616: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 10-29 16:11:24.616:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12870):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   10-29 16:11:24.616: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 10-29
>   16:11:24.616: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-29 16:11:24.616:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12870): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   10-29 16:11:24.616: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getInvocationHandler(Proxy.java:263) 10-29
>   16:11:24.616: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):    at
>   com.j256.ormlite.android.DatabaseTableConfigUtil.lookupClasses(Unknown
>   Source) 10-29 16:11:24.616: E/AndroidRuntime(12870):  at
>   com.j256.ormlite.android.DatabaseTableConfigUtil.(Unknown
>   Source)

is everyone meet same question,thanks

Answer (score 0):

I met the same question like yours. My solution is adding `-keepattributes *Annotation*` , and it works.
Hope can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I added these lines to my proguard-rules:

```
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class * { public <init>(android.content.Context); }
```